my VHDX partitions are broken and want to mount ntfs partition from this by start and end sector
I have a corrupt VHDX and I did find out with bitrecover tool that my NTFS partition in a VHDX File (455 GB in size) starts at sector 468992 and ends at sector 955658232. How can I mount this VHDX in WSL so that I can extract some data?
I found this: vhdx in ubuntu
But when I do this:
sudo mount -o ro,loop,offset=$((468992*512)) /mnt/j/ASUS-MINIPC/ASUS.VHDX /mnt/vhd/
I get:
mount: /mnt/vhd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
THanks
PS: I found also to convert vmdk to vhdx from
source FAQ
qemu-img.exe convert -p -f vmdk -O vhdx -o subformat=dynamic C:\Hyper-V\Imports\VMWare\FreeRadiusAAMES\FreeRadiusAAMES.vmdk C:\Hyper-V\VHDs\FreeRadius.vhdx
and from HOW-TO
qemu-img convert -f vmdk source.vmdk -O raw <path>
dd if=<path> of=/dev/<disk> bs=1G count=<target-gb-size>
Another alternativ approach is:

Mount EASUS_Partition_Manager.iso in VMWARE as DISK and boot from it
clone one VMDK DISK to a mounted physical disk by using EASUS.


Loop devices only support 'raw' images and do not understand the additional metadata and mapping tables found within VHDX or similar image formats. Trying to loop-mount a .vhdx will lead to the system trying to interpret VHDX metadata as if it were actual disk data.
Instead, use qemu-nbd (from 'qemu-tools') to attach the image:
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 -r -f vhdx ASUS.VHDX

The program will read the VHDX metadata and will present its contents through the specified nbd device, which you can then slice with addpart to make an nbd0p1 show up at the specified offset.
(Likewise, delpart can be used to remove unwanted nbd0pX slices in case the kernel detects an incorrect partition table. Other related tools: partprobe, partx, kpartx.)

Just for info: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/addpart.8.html

I could install qemu by sudo get install qemu-utils I do not have a /dev/nbd0 I get: wschrabi@DESKTOP-E2SI52K:/mnt/j/ASUS-MINIPC$ qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 -r -f vhdx ASUS.VHDX  I get qemu-nbd: Failed to open /dev/nbd0: No such file or directory

When I do: apt install nbd-serverand apt install nbd-clientand then modprobe nbd cd /dev ` I can mount the VHDX File as described above.

Just to complete: After creating the partition  /dev/nbd0p1 I had to mount by sudo mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt/nbd0p1
